# Python Preserving indentation afer modifying output

Tags: python, indentation

I have a code which parses a text file modifies the file but i need to **preserve the indentation** Please help me in acheiving preserved indentation!

Here's my code:

```
import re
import collections
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []

with open('text1238.txt','r+') as f:
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = group_pattern.match(line)
        if m:    # this is a group definition line
            group_name, group_members = m.groups()
            groups[group_name].members += filter(lambda x: x not in groups[group_name].members , group_members.split(','))
            current_group = group_name
        else:
            if (current_group is not None) and (len(line) > 0):
                groups[current_group].text.append(line)
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()

    for group_name, group in groups.items():
        f.write("%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members)))
        f.write( '\n'.join(group.text) + '\n')
```

INPUT Text.txt

```
 Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw)
     The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
 ......

Car(Rangerover,audi,Hummer)
     SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

Expected Output Text.txt

```
 Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw,Rangerover,Hummer)
     The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
 ......
     SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

But getting output as:

```
Car(skoda,audi,benz,bmw,Rangerover,Hummer)
The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
......
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

How do i preserve the indentation?
Please help me to fix my code!Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: When you read the input file you perform a strip() on the line.   This removes any spaces, tabs, \n from start and end of line.  Perhaps you should use rstrip() which will only remove trailing whitespace

Comment: could u please put r.strip() into my code i dont know where to fix that?

Comment: where should i use it?

Comment: line = line.strip()  # change this
        m = group_pattern.match(line)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `line = line.strip()`. This will remove the indentation. Removing that line should preserve indentation, although you might need to adjust the regular expression (not for the code shown, though).

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

```
groups[current_group].text.append(line)
```

with:

```
groups[current_group].text.append('\t' + line)
```

This will add tab for indention. Or if you want spaces you can use `'    '` (four spaces) instead if `'\t'`.